# Vb.net Updating Datagrid View with data from multiple Datatables

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have two Data tables and they have Asset mapping (Asset ID's & EmpID's tagged to each asset) and Associate Details (EmpID of all associates in a company). Now I want to have a third Data table built, which shows the assets that are not tagged to a valid associate, i.e., the EmpID in First Data table should not be present in Second Data table.

In SQL terms it will be:

```
Select AssetID, UserID from AssetMapping
Where UserID Not In (Select EmpID from AssociateDetail)
```

How can I accomplish the task of getting the result in a third data table (which I need to show in a data grid view later)?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between UserID and EmpID. Can you write the structure of your 2 tables?

Comment: UserID & EmpID are one and the same. Its denoted in 2 different names in 2 different sources. Basically its the primary key. Thanks for your below suggestion, I will try implementing it & let you know the end result.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't understood where UserID is stored but it shouldn't matter too much.

In this small example you use LINQ to build your third table data, starting from your first 2 tables (`AssetMapping` and `AssociateDetails`). The final result is a 3rd table filled with Asset not matching any EmpID in your Associate table

Result:
[image]

Basically I fill my database tables `AssetMapping` and `AssociateDetails`.
Then when I click on `Button1` I save a list of `EmpID`, and get a set of `AssetID` that is NOT linked to any of these `EmpID`.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.AssociateDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StackOverflowDataSet.AssociateDetails)
        Me.AssetMappingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StackOverflowDataSet.AssetMapping)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim EmpIdsList = (From em In StackOverflowDataSet.AssociateDetails
                              Select em.Field(Of Int32)("EmpID")).ToList()

        Dim q = From myRow In StackOverflowDataSet.AssetMapping
                Where EmpIdsList.Contains(myRow.Field(Of Int32)("EmpID")) = False
                Select myRow
        DataGridView3.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        DataGridView3.DataSource = q.ToList()
    End Sub
End Class
```